# Is there a difference in semantics between python 2 and python 3 for optimized expressions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I had a Python 2 script that creates a bunch `Thread` objects into a list:

```
myWorkers = [ MyThread(num)  for num in range(5) ]
```

Directly below that I started all of them:

```
map(lambda t: t.start(), myWorkers)
```

which should just call `start()` on all members of that list.

My thread class has `__init__` overridden and some output in `run()`:

```
class MyThread(Thread):
  def __init__(self, num):
    super(MyThread, self).__init__(name="Thread-%s" % num)
    self.num = num
  def run(self):
    logger.debug("My thread run() %s" % self.getName())
    ...
```

All works fine in Python 2.

Then I migrated the module to Python 3 and... I never saw the message `My thread run()...` anymore. Strange.

But when I change the code for calling `start()` to:

```
for i, t in enumerate(myWorkers):
    logger.debug("starting my-worker %d..." % i)
    t.start()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

everything was back to normal.

It seems to me that the semantics for the call of

```
map(lambda t: t.start(), myWorkers)
```

must have changed. Is that the case? Has it been optimized out because I do not assign the result anywhere? Or am I overlooking somehting else?

Comment: Style tip: map and list comprehensions are usually employed when you want to do something with the resulting list/generator. Otherwise, it may make more sense to use a regular for loop: `for t in myWorkers: t.start()`. This is actually fewer characters than `map(lambda t: t.start(), myWorkers)`.